# Execute Jquery on linkbutton click

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to execute the following jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnReset').click(function () {
        $('#txtFirstName').val('');
    });
});
```

The error is:

> uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

on link button click, which is as follows;

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnReset" CssClass="btnReset" runat="server">RESET</asp:LinkButton>
```

But, I don't know why it is not working, Please assist me if anybody knows that. Thanks.

Comment: put an alert to check is it called??

Comment: is `#txtFirstName` a client-side input (`<input type="text" />`), or an `<asp:Textbox />` control?

Comment: Actually, it is giving me an error as "uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined." when i tried debugging it in browser. What's this?

Comment: If `$` is not defined, you are either calling the script before jQuery has loaded or jQuery is not linked to the page.

Comment: @pete I tried writing the code in the head section of the page after all the scripts has been loaded, but still it is giving the same error.

Comment: Can you include the rendered `head` section in your question?

Comment: Ahhh..silly me, I accidently deleted the jquery reference from the head section. Now it is calling the function but still not emptying the textbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54875/discussion-between-pete-and-learner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net changes Ids when rendering server side controls on client side, so i suspect that textbox value is not changed because of this so do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnReset').click(function () {
        $("#<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>").val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using the client side control.

Comment: If you add runat="server" the control is server side its obvious